# Return specific row using offset or lead or lag

Tags: sql-server, fetch, offset

I have two tables; #tempA  and #tempB
I want to join both tables matching on Student_id and Admit_date.
I want to return the #tempB table row immediately after the row that matches on student_id and admit date.
In this case, I want to return #tempB rows 2, row 5 and row 18.
I can't get it to work.

---

tempA

```
Student_id  Admit_date
709652      2020-01-31 
709652      2019-10-09 
368671      2015-04-19
```

tempB

```
Unique_id   Student_id  Admit date
1           709652      2020-01-31 
2           709652      2019-12-16 
3           709652      2019-12-04 
4           709652      2019-10-09 
5           709652      2019-10-07 
6           709652      2019-09-22 
7           709652      2019-09-21 
8           709652      2019-08-29 
9           709652      2019-08-01 
10          709652      2019-07-01 
11          709652      2019-06-24 
12          709652      2019-03-25 
13          709652      2019-03-14 
14          709652      2014-03-31 
15          709652      2016-06-23 
16          709652      2014-05-14 
17          368671      2015-04-19 
18          368671      2014-04-10 
19          368671      2014-04-01 
20          368671      2014-03-21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT a.Student_id , a.Admit_date,
    (   SELECT MIN( b.Admit_date)
        FROM tempB b
        WHERE b.Admit_date >= a.Admit_date
        AND a.Student_id = b.Student_id
    ) as Admit_date2

FROM tempA a
```

Comment: That did not work.  i want to join both tables and return records 2,5 and 18.